# SWT Composite. Обработка нажатия кнопки мыши

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Есть Composite, внутри которого размещены несколько Composite. Задачи состоит в том, чтобы при любом нажатии кнопки мыши в области прорисовки этого Composite и его потомков изменить его background. Прямое решение - для самого Composite и всех его потомков зарегистрировать listener на нажатие кнопки мыши, внутри которого и будет происходить изменение background-а. Соответственно, если у Composite много потомков(вложенные Composite, кнопки, ExpandBar-ы и т.п.), то код станет довольно громоздким и трудно сопровождаемым. Есть ли другие подходы, более элегантные что-ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взять в цикле корень и всех потомков и навесить на них обработчики событий?
Код будет несколько громоздким (если вариантов реакций на событие много), но в одном конкретном месте.

Можно рекурсивно пройти по дереву.

А так - да, каждому элементу - свой обработчик события.